# bcoin daemon killed over and over again [BCOIN]

Tags: full-node, bcoin

I am setting up a full bitcoin node using BCOIN.

I spinned up a VPS on Google Cloud. Specs: 2 CPUs and 7.5 GB of RAM. 500gb of standard storage. OS: Linux ubuntu.

As I start the daemon, things go well at first. Then, I receive less and less blocks and after 10-15 minutes the daemon gets killed.

I even tried to beef up my VPS with 4 CPU and 15 GB of RAM. I also added a SWAP file. Same resault: deamon dead after 10 minutes.

I checked resource consumpion and it seems that there is plenty of spare RAM and CPU. So the VPS set up is not a problem.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ? Thanks :-)

Comment: Are you running the latest version master branch on github? Feel free to tell us your specific config, etc on IRC #bcoin (freenode) or on our slack, https://bcoin.io/slack-signup.html And what version of nodejs are you running? Minimum for bcoin is 10.0... See also this issue: https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/issues/899

Answer (score 1):

At this time, bcoin requires nodejs version 10.0 or greater.